# Screen scraping silverlight browser application info

Tags: silverlight, screen-scraping

I'm registered to a site which uses a silverlight application that shows some personal information.

My goal is to be able to read some data from the silverlight application.

Is it possible?

I know that this could be done to a regular web page using curl.
but, what about silverlight application?

Does it store the information to a file or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [White](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=white), a tool for automating windows applications, to get information out of a running Silverlight application. White is mainly used to perform functional testing of applications, but it should allow you to extract information from the application as well.

Look here for an example of White and Silverlight: http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=white

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.
Can it generate a mouse click on some button?

Comment: Yep. Check out the documentation :-)